# Check the element of a vetcor is between the element of second vector in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors. I want to check the first element of first vector is between first and second element of second vector , then check the second element of first vector is between the third and forth element of the second vector ,.....How can I do this in R?

For example, If we have tow vectors

```
   a = c(1.5, 2, 3.5)
   b = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 8)
```

the final result in R should be for 1.5 is TRUE and 3.5 is TRUE and for 2 is FALSE.

Comment: How is this question different to your previous question?

Comment: @mnel This is a different question because the length of first vector is half of the length of second vector and I just want to check the first element of first vector is just between first and second element of second vector or not, do not want to check is between th other elements of second vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
s <- seq_along(a)  
b[s] < a[s] & a[s] < b[s+1]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c(1.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,4)

y <- 1:5

x > y & x < c(y[-1],NA)

#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You need to take care of vector lengths and think about, what you want the result to be for the last element of x and of course.

More robust solution:

```
x <- c(1.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,4)
findInterval(x,y) == seq_along(x)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

x1 <- c(1.5,3.5)
findInterval(x1,y) == seq_along(x1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE

x2 <- c(1.5,3.5,1:5+0.5)
findInterval(x2,y) == seq_along(x2)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: The length of first vector is half of second one. This means that I do not want to check the first element of first vector is just between first and second element of second vector , not to check the other value of second vector, and the second element of first is just between third and forth element of second vector or not.How can I do this?

Comment: I do not understand your comment at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not an ideal and fastest solution, but it works.

```
a <- rnorm(99)
b <- rnorm(100)
m <- cbind(b[-length(b)], b[-1])
a > m[,1] & a < m[,2]
```

You should check the lengths of both initial vectors.

Here is one-line solution:

```
sapply(1:length(a), function(i) {a[i] > b[i] & a[i] < b[i+1]})
```

Comment: No need for a loop here.

Comment: Of course, it is just for illustration. Your solution is very nice.